# Using multiple MySQL databases with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have multiple websites based on CI and they all use their own default DBs and work just fine.

Now I have a requirement where one of the websites connect to the DB of another website to get some info (they are on same server) but maintain the native DB connection.

I'm using following code to connect to other website DB

```
$dsn = 'mysql://econnect_base_user:econnect_base_pass@localhost/econnect_base_db';
$city_db = $this->load->database($dsn, TRUE);
```

the problem is this resets the default DB and closing the 'city_db' and trying to reconnect the default DB won't work (may be it's the dumbest thing to do but I don't have any other idea!)

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link --- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html at "Connecting to Multiple Databases"

Comment: what's your config for the default db look like?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html):

> If you need to connect to more than one database simultaneously you
>   can do so as follows:
>
> ```
> $DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
> $DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
> ```
>
> Note: Change the words "group_one" and "group_two" to the specific
>   group names you are connecting to (or you can pass the connection
>   values as indicated above).
>
> By setting the second parameter to TRUE (boolean) the function will
>   return the database object.
>
> When you connect this way, you will use your object name to issue
>   commands rather than the syntax used throughout this guide. In other
>   words, rather than issuing commands with:
>
> ```
> $this->db->query(); 
> $this->db->result(); 
> //etc...
> ```
>
> You will instead use:
>
> ```
> $DB1->query(); 
> $DB1->result();
> ```

Comment: yeah well I don't think I can do that, I know and am using the same on some of the websites.

but here the DB details in the DSN string comes from a database and not from database.php and it's based on the request which can come from any of the multiple websites and I kind of require an quick connection to other DB, grab the data and done!

Comment: So instead jsut supply the DSN to one of them: `$remote = $this->load->database($dsn, true); $local = $this->load->database('default');`

Comment: yes I tried that but it doesn't seem to work! I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain php db stuff:

```
$other_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$other_db_name", $other_db_user, $other_db_pass);
foreach ($other_dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row)
    process_info($row);
```

Comment: why would you use plain php when CI has a wrapper for this already?

Answer (score 0):

At First setup two database connections in config/database.php. By default you will see the following one.

```
$active_group = 'default';
    $active_record = TRUE;
    $db['default']['hostname'] = '';
    $db['default']['username'] = '';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $db['default']['database'] = '';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Add another db connection settings  as $db['another_db'] as following

```
    $db['another_db']['hostname'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['username'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['password'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['database'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['another_db']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['another_db']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['another_db']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['another_db']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['another_db']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['another_db']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['another_db']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['another_db']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Then for the default database, you just do the normal query after loading the database.

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->query($sql); 
$this->db->result();
```

For loading another_db and making query,

```
$another_db= $this->load->database('another_db', TRUE);
$another_db->query($sql); 
$another_db->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this code in your config/database.php
Hope this work for you.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

// first db configuration
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; // Hostname
$db['default']['username'] = 'root'; // username
$db['default']['password'] = ''; // password
$db['default']['database'] = 'first_db'; // replace your database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


// second db configuration
$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; // Hostname
$db['db2']['username'] = 'root'; // username
$db['db2']['password'] = ''; // password
$db['db2']['database'] = 'second_db'; // replace your database name
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

You can use both database anywhere by loading database

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->database;
$this->db->database2;
$this->db->query('your query');
```

Comment: While the code you've provided may include the answer to the OP's problem - the post is not very useful without an explanation of how you've solved their issue.

Comment: Well lets close down Stack Overflow now then.